# Scala patternmatching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have following code for pattern matching in Scala:

```
response.flatMap(employee =>
            employee match {
              case e if e.type == Manager => e.headoffice
              case e if e.type == Clerk => e.branch
              case _ => None
            }
          )
```

Is this optimum way of doing pattern matching? Can it be made more concise?

Comment: What is `e.type` here? A custom method? Anyways, you can remove the whole `employee => employee match {` and just do `response.flatMap { case ... }`

Comment: e.type is a field in Employee, of enumeration type

Comment: `e.type` is the singleton type of `e`. What Scala version is supposed to compile this? What weird parallel universe does this entire thread live in, neither the question nor the answers make any sense... O_o??

Comment: @AndreyTyukin in anyone, you just need to use backticks to scape the `type` field: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/jV1iSWOHQEuiXobySFvpqw/2 - I didn't want to focus on that since OP already mentioned it was a field. - Anyways, edited my answer to be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try matching on `type`:

```
response.flatMap(e => e.type match {
    case Manager => e.headoffice
    case Clerk => e.branch
    case _ => None
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally would do it like this:

```scala
response.map(e => e -> e.`type`).flatMap {
  case (e, Manager) => e.headoffice
  case (e, Clerk) => e.branch
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: On which version does this compile?